# Why the F test is NA in R package Fect?

Tags: r, panel-data, f-test

I am a new learner of Fect package in R, see https://yiqingxu.org/packages/fect/fect.html.
I try to use method to do counterfactual analysis of my DiD. I use unbalanced panel data, and the Matrix Completion method, but I got NA in F test when testing Pre-Trend(MC)? Does anyone know the reason? What should I do? Thank you!

[image]